# how to make the new component popup a list of option when the first click on the new component?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

My source is resided in [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ul9ymf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdivision-list-input-box%2Fdivision-list-input-box.component.ts).

I have an input box, I put many features to the input box (the left one).

I want to pack it into a component (the right one).

Lucky the new component working properly except the first click response.

The original input box will popup a list of option when the first click of the input box.

However, the new component does not popup a list of option when the first click of the component,

the component will popup a list of option after the first click or when a key is pressed.

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with life-cycle hooks. When you assign `this.filteredDivisionList = this.divisionList;` in the component constructor, the `this.divisionList` is `undefined` or `null`, use `ngOnChnages()` lifecycle hook to assigne `input()` values, because this method:

Respond when Angular (re)sets data-bound input properties. The method receives a `SimpleChanges` object of current and previous property values.
Called before `ngOnInit()` and whenever one or more data-bound input properties change.''

Comment: I have modified the code accordingly, it does not work.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qqc9sb?file=src/app/division-list-input-box/division-list-input-box.component.ts

Comment: Why the "app.component.ts" does not need to implement the "ngOnChnages" method?

Comment: In `app.component.ts` you have an initialized array of strings: `divisionList=["A1","A6","D1","D3","D5","F2","F21","F22","F4","F41","F42","F5","F6","R1","R2","R3","R4"];` You don't get the data from `input()`.